# JavaScript change elements color and store with LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, onload

I want to make a button that changes the elements color and store the changed color with LocalStorage. To be honest I am a newby in LocalStorage, but I tried my best. It's almost works, but a bit buggy, and not really saves the changes. Any idea how to make it workable?

Code:

```js
function markasRead() {

    var message = document.getElementById("msgContainer");
    var marbtn = document.getElementById("markasread");

    const wasRead = localStorage.getItem('message') === 'true';

    if (!message.classList.contains("readMsg")) {
        marbtn.innerHTML = "Mark as unread";
        localStorage.setItem('message', !wasRead);
        message.classList.toggle("readMsg", !wasRead);
    } else if (message.classList.contains("readMsg")) {
        message.classList.remove("readMsg");
        message.classList.toggle("readMsg", wasRead);
        marbtn.innerHTML = "Mark as read";
    }

}

function onloadread() {
    message.classList.toggle('readMsg', localStorage.getItem('message') === 'true');
}
```

```css
#msgContainer {
  background-color: red;
}

.readMsg {
    background-color: gray !important;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onloadread()">
<div id="msgContainer">
Some text...<br>
<button id="markasread" onclick="markasRead()">Mark as read</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code and tell me, if this is what you want to achieve.

```
function markasRead() {
  const message = document.getElementById("msgContainer");
  const marbtn = document.getElementById("markasread");
  const wasRead = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('message'));
  if (!wasRead || wasRead === false) {
    marbtn.innerHTML = "Mark as unread";
  } else {
    marbtn.innerHTML = "Mark as read";
  }
  localStorage.setItem('message', !wasRead);
  message.classList.toggle("readMsg");
}

function onloadread() {
  const message = document.getElementById("msgContainer");
  const marbtn = document.getElementById("markasread");
  if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('message'))) {
    marbtn.innerHTML = "Mark as unread";
    message.classList.toggle('readMsg');
  }
}
```

Comment: It is almost what I want, but it should keep the changed color when reload the page.

Comment: it should keep the color changed. its working over here. Maybe clean your local storage once and try it again.

Comment: I don't know why, I cleaned the LocalStorage but it still doesn't keep the chenged color. :/

Comment: are you maybe in incognito mode? local storage doesn't work in incognito mode. however, here you can test it out yourself https://jsfiddle.net/0n7629wk/

Comment: Yeah I can clearly see it's working but I don't know why is it not working for me. Maybe I'll try it with another browser or another computer. Btw thank you for everything!